# git repository broken after power cut

Tags: git

My git repository is in a bad shape after a power cut.

I would like to save this git repository because I have local branches that only exist in this local repository.

```
$ git co master 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    some_file
    another_file
```

All the files in the repository appear new and yet, they are just the same as before:

```
$ git status
On branch my_branch
Initial commit
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .gitignore
    new file:   BUILD.md
    new file:   CONTRIBUTING.md
    new file:   README.md
    new file:   STYLE.md
    ...
    new file:   pom.xml
    new file:   rename.py
```

I have this too:

```
$ git gc
error: Could not read e39f7f1d41e57c37f22d09c005d660258bbc6343
fatal: bad tree object e39f7f1d41e57c37f22d09c005d660258bbc6343
error: failed to run repack

$ git log
fatal: your current branch 'my_branch' does not have any commits yet

$ git log master -2
commit e98facb7a7fdcb9f7d82955db15a7c120d140170
Author: Jean-Noël Rouvignac
Date:   Thu Sep 13 16:00:38 2018 +0200
    ...
commit 962fc48c67aebdc847ccb8af3c76ce1996b0fe46
Author: Jean-Noël Rouvignac
Date:   Thu Sep 13 15:04:02 2018 +0200
    ...

$ git log HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ cat .git/HEAD 
ref: refs/heads/my_branch

$ cat .git/logs/refs/heads/my_branch
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 e98facb7a7fdcb9f7d82955db15a7c120d140170 Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536927392 +0200  branch: Created from HEAD
e98facb7a7fdcb9f7d82955db15a7c120d140170 96a7d8563363b15b91bdd5c2724007cc8c036bcd Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536927529 +0200  commit: some commit
96a7d8563363b15b91bdd5c2724007cc8c036bcd 9d393e866cf3dd07d307f537c632ca5176e7c1a9 Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536927741 +0200  commit (amend): some commit
9d393e866cf3dd07d307f537c632ca5176e7c1a9 bff18f48aa48e06f438fb313b1fa5fba00ff15f1 Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536930612 +0200  commit: another commit
bff18f48aa48e06f438fb313b1fa5fba00ff15f1 563fe6ce2c56bb078fb2b77c3b95f9ee35fb8d20 Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536930614 +0200  cherry-pick: another commit yet
563fe6ce2c56bb078fb2b77c3b95f9ee35fb8d20 fb859a42f3e3115c15e618193285666c6c26a45e Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536930625 +0200  rebase -i (finish): refs/heads/my_branch onto bff18f48aa48e06f438fb313b1fa5fba00ff15f1
fb859a42f3e3115c15e618193285666c6c26a45e 9bde6d1f18b3abbbb85c8292ac317595a07671a1 Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536931081 +0200  commit (amend): another commit
9bde6d1f18b3abbbb85c8292ac317595a07671a1 509667f1e8b0ea3551b18675322fed7559c2b0fd Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536931501 +0200  commit (amend): another commit
509667f1e8b0ea3551b18675322fed7559c2b0fd c76770fe2986ccfe24bfb76847d9c037f4bad65b Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536931578 +0200  commit (amend): another commit
c76770fe2986ccfe24bfb76847d9c037f4bad65b 10c7f4fe48c29668268bcf956620ce09f367b183 Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536932495 +0200  commit (amend): another commit
10c7f4fe48c29668268bcf956620ce09f367b183 94de94f1e1df660730ed7846f1e6d5bd76f50abe Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536933394 +0200  commit (amend): another commit
94de94f1e1df660730ed7846f1e6d5bd76f50abe 6386448321ac4b49e8e8fb65e1494d5f3307f5d8 Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536938691 +0200  cherry-pick: DO NOT MERGE
6386448321ac4b49e8e8fb65e1494d5f3307f5d8 37d78592e6179b1c07c181e469310bcdd74322bb Jean-Noël Rouvignac 1536950131 +0200  commit: fixup
```

The repository is important to me, so I would like to save it.

Has anybody got an idea on what could go wrong and how to fix it?

I am a bit lost on what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, a power outage shouldn't impact the integrity of the Git repository itself. However, if your filesystem isn't journalized, it can break the file currently being written.

So what you need is to repair your filesystem first aside any Git operation, by umounting your partition then checking it with `fsck` (*filesystem check*) from the shell. Your distribution should be able to do that on startup, though.

Then, you want to repair inconsistencies in the Git repository itself using :

```
git fsck
```

This command is named after the "true" filesystem repair command, but actually tries to fix inconsistencies in the history graph and look for dangling/loose objects.

Since a git repository is actually made of individual, independent object files (that simply refer to each other), the powercut shouldn't have jeopardized the whole collection. You probably lost almost nothing in this event.

If the above doesn't help, try to manually get back to the last known commit :

```
git reset --soft 37d78592e6179b1c07c181e469310bcdd74322bb
git stash
git branch -f my_branch
git checkout my_branch
git stash pop
```

You'll then should end back with all your changes as "unstaged" stuff. You'll then be able to prepare another commit.

Comment: That did not work:

```
$ git reset --soft 37d78592e6179b1c07c181e469310bcdd74322bb
$ git stash
fatal: unable to read tree e92224b11f09a98e4916de97313a259e4ab0d360
Cannot save the current worktree state
$ git branch -f my_branch 
fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.
$ git status
fatal: unable to read 2b7b3df98650e3b0315bb2f985d6f4abdca21b9f
```

Comment: What did `git fsck` do ?

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to report it. Here it is:```$ git fsck
Segmentation faultrectories:   2% (6/256)   
``` Thanks for your help!

Comment: That doesn't look good :( Trying to upgrade my distribution to get a more recent version for git

Comment: Indeed, a segmentation fault while checking repository's integrity should be considered as a Git bug. But it's most likely due to the fact that your filesystem itself is still in inconsistent state. You need to run `fsck` (the original command) on it but for this, you must unmount it first. If you're working in your home dir, you may need to go in single mode first (at boot time or calling `init 1` from a shell). From here, you'll be prompted for *root* password (not the sudo's one) then fall back on a shell from where you'll be able to unmount/fsck your partition.

Comment: Upgrading to a more recent git helped. I am not sure which version I was on, but I am now on 2.17.1 . I was on linux mint 18 and upgraded to linux mint 19. Here is what git fsck reported: https://gist.github.com/JnRouvignac/ba0f8897e172871528a7ef3b3c03e0f1

Comment: The dangling commits look to be stashes.

Comment: I am going to look at `fsck` now. Thanks a lot for your help Obsidian!